# Why can't we use O-Notation to compare algorithms?

Tags: algorithm, performance, complexity-theory, notation

From my textbook:

> *O-notation and Complexity of Algorithms*
>
> It is important not to try and make comparisons between algorithms
>   using O-notation.
>
> For example, suppose algorithm A1 and A2 both solve the same
>   problem, A1 has complexity O(n^3) and A2 has complexity O(n^2).
>
> The above statements are perfectly reasonable.
>
> Observe that we cannot conclude that A2 is more efficient than A1 in
>   this situation!

Why not? Complexity of A2 grows slower than A1.

Comment: In the example listed, all Big-O notation tells you is that at *some point* A1 grows faster than A2, making A2 the better choice. It doesn't tell you when that point is. It's when you don't take this into account that comparisons become a problem. There's a few algorithms that have exceptionally Big O's, but the hidden constants are so high as to make the algorithms impractical in practice for all but the most ridiculously large problem sizes.

Comment: It would probably help to insert "*general*" or "*sweeping*" before "*comparisons*" in the first quoted sentence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Grows slower doesn't mean absolutely faster.

Do you have the experience that your friend was taller than you when you were younger, but you end up be the taller guy between you two, or the other way around?

That's the same meaning. A1 may be way more suitable and fast to solve a small scale problem. It just becomes slower when encountering big problems.

If you want to know more detail about the mathematical background, then "An Introduction to the Analysis of Algorithms" by Robert Sedgewick is highly recommended.

Answer (score 2):

First, there are unspecified constant factors as Mark Harrison pointed out.

Second, these are upper bounds. Log n is O(n^a) for every a>0. It could be that the O(n^3) algorithm is actually faster in every single case than the O(n^2) algorithm, the O(n^3) just wasn't the best possible bound. Use [omega](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Big_Omega_notation) or theta notation if you want to specify lower bounds.

Third, algorithmic complexity is usually an estimate on the worst-case performance. You might be interested in the average performance instead, or some other measure.

---

Some people go too far, perhaps out of a misunderstanding of the [No Free Lunch Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_free_lunch_in_search_and_optimization), and state that no algorithm is better than any other. As common sense indicates, some algorithms are better than others in any context you choose. If you understand the above caveats, computational complexity bounds can be a big hint about which algorithms are efficient or practicable when n is large.

Answer (score 1):

There is an (unspecified) constant value implied in big-O notation.  So you're actually being asked which of these is more efficient:

```
A1 = O(n^3) * n*K1
A2 = O(n^2) * n*K2
```

Without knowing the values of K1 and K2, it's impossible to say the exact runtimes for A1 and A2.  We know that the curve of A1 will eventually be larger than that of A2, but we don't know for what value of n.

There's also a potential constant setup time for A1 and A2 which might need to be taken into consideration.

```
A1 = O(n^3) * n*K1 + C1
A2 = O(n^2) * n*K2 + C2
```

Comment: O(n^3) includes `a*n^3 + b*n^2 + c*n + d` for any a,b,c,d. It's not just a linear addition. (And it could also include `log n` terms and lots of other stuff, but `a` (the inner loop time) is usually the most significant.)

Comment: You're correct if you add the phrase "as n grows without bounds" or "as n approaches infinity".  The key point is that for smaller values of n, algorithms with higher complexity but lower setup and per-operation time might be more efficient.